# Manage react apollo with redux observable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-apollo, redux-observable

I want to manage my fetching with redux observable but I can't find any example. Did somebody have an answer to that?

By apollo vanillaJS this is the way to get my query results :

```
const opts = {uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql'};
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface(opts);
const client = new ApolloClient({
networkInterface});

let query = gql`query {
                    viewer {
                        id
                        firstName
                        lastName
                        defaultTimeZoneId
                        defaultLanguage
                    }
                }`;
client.query({query}).then((results) => {})
//return a promise
```

Now I need to plug that in redux observable to manage the answer :

```
export const fetchActionGridDataEpic = action$ => 
  action$.ofType('FETCHING_ACTION_GRID_DATA')
//Execute the query then if networkStatus === 7 send the result to FETCHING_ACTION_GRID_DATA_FULFILLED as a payload
  .mapTo({ type: 'FETCHING_ACTION_GRID_DATA_FULFILLED' })....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `fromPromise` like so:

```
const fetchQuestionsEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_QUESTIONS)
  .mergeMap(() =>
    Observable.fromPromise(fetchQuestions())
      .map(questions => ({ type: QUESTIONS_FETCHED, questions })),
  );
```

This repo follows some good practices [github.com/voteetvous](https://github.com/voteetvous/app/tree/3fa4d241af4a3b9e3d0b326e51321d9f7510b5c4/client/src/redux/modules)